# Plug in (Virtual Goniometer) different floating point precision from the running MeshLab version

Tags: macos, plugins, meshlab

I want to use a MeshLab plugin (Virtual goniometer) with the Meshlab software however I keep getting an error. I have downloaded the MeshLab May 2021 version and MeshLab plugins as per
https://amaaze.umn.edu/sites/amaaze.umn.edu/files/2021-07/Meshlab_AMAAZE_Doc_0.pdf. and followed instructions until the end where I receive this error:
"libfilter_virtualgoniometer.so has different floating point precision from the running MeshLab version."

I have ejected and redownloaded MeshLab and Meshlab plugins. However, nothing has changed. Is this an apple problem? If anyone has suggestions as to how to navigate, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check the exact version of meshlab: there is `2021.05` and `2021.05d`. Be sure that the version of meshlab and the list of plugins matches.